# configuring Django Channels for windows in production

Tags: django, django-channels

Please, I need to configure Django Channels on redis-channel-layer on windows IIS in production. It is running very well in development.

I have installed redis, daphne. I have set the IIS as proxy server with URL Rewrite pointing the Inbound to  localhost 6379 to redis-layer channels. I used python manage.py runworker. and also started the daphne server with the daphne command.

They all ran very well, but there is no websocket handshake for my url.

Comment: Can you post your development settings